# Why i can't use a result from a select query to be the name of a table in another selecr query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM (select area from clubs where CLUB = 'AVR')
```

I want use the resut from de second select to be the table's name to the first selection, but sql server don't acept this code. Help please :(

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql for this.

Comment: `SELECT` statement always returns a **row** (even if it contains just a single column).

Comment: So you mean you store table names in `club`'s column `area`?

Comment: OT: This questions makes me think, that you are running with a bad design. You should not keep your data for different Clubs in differently named tables. Rather have them in one table and use a 1:n-relation...

Comment: Shell we wait for the OP to clarify?

Comment: Hi :) I have 40 clubs that i divided by regions... Eatch region (country) have 10 clubs. When the user select a club, that should be able to show only the table of this region. So when the user want select values from this club, need to show that data from the correct table (in this case, club AVR belongs to table 'TIMETABLE_POR_NOR'. (sorry my english :) )

Comment: That's pretty bad design. Store the data for all regions in one common table, not in different ones.

Comment: You are using separate tables when you should be using a column in your table. The region is nothing more than a property of a club, not a separate table. You are fighting getting your data back out because you made some bad decisions in your design. If you fix the design, retrieving information is a LOT easier.

Comment: I stand corrected :-)

Comment: But if 40 clubs use only one table to store data, in one year i will have more than 40.000.000 rows. Then the performance will be affected!  Eatch group of 10 clubs represents a country.
It was not me who started the project, I have to give continuity to what is in use.

Comment: 40 000 000 or 1 000 000 makes no difference if properly indexed.

Comment: 40 mln row isn't big problem in well designed (denormalised and indexed) database. Probably this calculation is wrong because of wrong design)

Comment: @JacekCz I think you meant to say normalized not denormalized. :D

Comment: Yes :) .. "denormalised" first concept should be normalised.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this, but only with dynamic SQL.  First, I assign the result of your subquery to a session variable, then I use this to build a dynamic `SELECT *` query.

```
SET @TableName = (SELECT TOP(1) area from clubs where CLUB = 'AVR')
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

I have added `TOP(1)` to the subquery to ensure that only a single table name is returned.

Comment: In the spirit of holidays :-)

Comment: You are solving a different problem.  OP's `area` contains table **names**.

Comment: @PM77-1, don't see any difference though ... what difference you talking about?

Comment: @Rahul He wants to take `area` and then use that dynamically as a table name in the outer query.

Comment: *I want use the resut from de second select to be the table's name to the first selection* -> Only dynamically

Comment: Ahh!!! @PM77-1 got it now. pretty sure OP is in confused mind state and actually don't mean what he says in post

Comment: jarlh - Hey men... I'm perfectly aware that the best option should be use only one table but it was not me who started the project and i have to give continuity to what is in use. If you can't or not want help, please at least do not be rude. Tanks for your help.